# Node.js call async function from within do while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, do-while

I want to call an async function from within a do while loop and exit only if the function doesn't return a value. 
Is there a way to manage this without having to actually *wait* outside the callback?

Here's the code that obviously always exits in the first loop since the function hasn't called back yet, when the while () is evaluated:

```js
var i = 0;
do {
  var foundListing;
  if (i) {
    listing.slug = listing.slug + '-' + (i + 1);
  }
  listingService.getListingBySlug(listing, function(error, pFoundListing) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(util.errorParser(error));
    } else if (Object.keys(pFoundListing).length) {
      foundListing = pFoundListing;
      i++;
    }
  });
  //Do I have to wait here???
} while (foundListing && Object.keys(foundListing).length);
```

**For Clarification:**
The point here is to generate a unique slug. If the slug already exists, i append a number and check again if it exists. When I get to the number that doesn't exist yet, I'm done.

**Update:**
I found a way using recursion. I posted the working snippet as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41695785/2639357).

Comment: where is the declaration of variable 'i'..

Comment: You're trying to fit an asynchronous call in a synchronous structure. Basically the code continuously fire  calls to  `listingService.getListingBySlug` at each iteration of the loop, at maximum speed javascript can execute that loop. Are you sure is what you want to do?

Comment: @GiacomoCosimato It's the opposite. Since `foundListing` is empty in the beginning the `while()` part always evaluates to false in the first loop because it is set within the callback, which hasn't been executed yet. Either way, that's not what I want. I want to only enter the loop again, if the a listing has been found in `listingService.getListingBySlug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work using recursion as suggested by Giacomo Cosimato.

Here's the snippet that worked:

listingController.js

```js
saveListing: function(listing, callback) {
  listingService.findOpenSlug(listing, listing.slug, 1, function(error, listing) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(util.errorParser(error));
    } else {
      listingService.saveListing(listing, function(error, savedListing) {
        //do some work
      });
    }
  });
}
```

listingService.js

```js
var classMethods = {
  findOpenSlug: function(listing, baseSlug, i, callback) {
    listingRepository.getListingBySlug(listing.slug, function(error, foundListing) {
      if (error) {
        return callback(error);
      } else if (Object.keys(foundListing).length) {
        listing.slug = baseSlug + '-' + (i + 1)
        i++;
        classMethods.findOpenSlug(listing, baseSlug, i, callback);
      } else {
        callback(null, listing);
      }
    });
  },
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the possiblity to test it, but maybe a recursive function should do:

```js
const listingService = {
  getListingBySlug(listing, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (listing.slug === 'listing-5') {
        callback(
          false,
          {
            name: 'Listing 1',
            slug: 'listing-1',
          }
        );
      }
      else {
        callback(false, {});
      }
    }, 1000);
  },
};

function checkListingExists(slug) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const listing = { slug };
    listingService.getListingBySlug(listing, (error, pFoundListing) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else if (Object.keys(pFoundListing).length) {
        resolve(pFoundListing);
      } else {
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
  });
}

function nextListing(prefix, index) {
  checkListingExists(prefix + '-' + index)
  .then((listing) => {
    if (listing === false) {
      nextListing(prefix, index + 1);
    } else {
      console.log(listing);
    }
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // deal with error response
  });
}

nextListing('listing', 0);
```

Comment: Hey! Ty for the answer! I was just working on a recursive way to solve this.  I also believe this is the only way. I will test and update.

Comment: Consider that the approach is to loop server requests until you find a "non used slug", but this is far from optimal performance wise.
I don't know if you own the API, but if you do, it would much better to implement a method like `getFirstAvailableListing(slug)` or something similar

Comment: I do own the API but the loop has to be somewhere on the server, doesn't it? The only other way I can think of is to fetch all listings with `slug = newSlug*` from the database and then determine via regex which would be the first non used slug

Comment: That's right. The thing is, image if you have a thousand listings and you have to check each one of them in sequence, waiting every time for server response. If is the only option, than go for it of course.

Comment: The consideration is, that this should be an edge case. Users are allowed to create listings. The listing's title, that the user creates is turned into a slug. If the two users create listings with titles that generate the same slug this logic comes to live. I only check if the slug exists, if it does I append a number and check if that slug exists, etc.. It's highly unlikely that this has to be done more than a few times, even with 10k listings +. Good point to consider, still.

Comment: I added my working example as an answer as well: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41695785/2639357)

Answer (score 0):

You should use promise in such cases. You can do something like this.

```
    var DEFERRED = require('deferred');
    var deferred = new DEFERRED();
    var i =0;

    while(1) {      
      listingService.getListingBySlug(listing, function(error, pFoundListing) {
    if (error) {
      return callback(util.errorParser(error));
      deferred.reject();
      break;
    } else if (Object.keys(pFoundListing).length) {         
      i++;
      listing.slug = listing.slug + '-' + (i + 1); 
      if(pFoundListing) {deferred.resolve()}
      break;
    }
  });


  deferred.promise.then(function() {
    // You will have the listing.slug value here.
  });
```

Btw you should not use Object.keys() to determine whether the object is empty or not. Simply create your own isEmpty method somewhere in utils file and check for the properties. If your pFoundListing is very large it will have the severe performance issue. For small objects (array) you would not notice the difference.

Comment: Ty for the answer! But wouldn't that potentially loop 1.000 times if the callback takes long enough?

Comment: `SyntaxError: Illegal break statement`